# JOptionPane not working

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

What's wrong with the following code? I'm getting "Tool completed with exit code 1" which doesn't tell me much. I want to prompt user for input, take input, parse it to an int, and then display the value in another message dialogue.

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane
    public class First
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many?");
            int ans = Integer.parseInt(result);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("You have " + ans + " Things.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: First Google's result for `JOptionPane`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html Spend some time improving your Google skills. It will save you (and other people) lot of time in the future.

Answer (score 4):

For one, `showMessageDialog` *has* no overloaded method that takes only a String parameter

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("You have " + ans + " Things.");
```

You need a parent component argument.. which can be null

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have " + ans + " Things.");
```

See [JOptionPane Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html)

---

Also not sure if that's your complete code, but you never declare `result`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class First {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many?");
        int ans = Integer.parseInt(result);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have " + ans + " Things.");
    }
}
```